# Dynamically setting event listeners (on click) in JQuery in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I iterate through an array of custom objects, and for each object in the array I create a button with an on click event listener, setting the results of the on click event dynamically. In other words, a click on button A might result in an alert 'foo', and a click on button B might result on a different behavior - alert 'bar'.

My JSHint linter says "Don't make functions within a loop".

I was hoping the SO community could share a better design pattern for achieving this goal (vanilla js or JQuery).

Check out the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/intelligence_ai/84v3qeyh/) - this is an extremely simplified version of what I am doing, but illustrates the point.

**Javascript (ES6):**

```
class Tool {
 constructor (name, mainFunction) {
  this.name = name;
  this.mainFunction = mainFunction;
 }
 getName() {
   return this.name;
 }
 getMainFunction() {
   return this.mainFunction;
 }
}

var hammer = new Tool('hammer', 'bang on nails');
var saw = new Tool('saw', 'cuts heavy wood');
var toolbox = [hammer, saw];

for (let i in toolbox) {
  $('.wrapper').append('<div class=\"'+toolbox[i].getName()+'  button\">'+toolbox[i].getName()+'</div>');
  $('.wrapper').on('click', '.'+toolbox[i].getName(), function() {
    alert(toolbox[i].getMainFunction());
   });
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="wrapper">
 Buttons:
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply assign the click functionality to the shared class `.button` and also assign the messages to a `data` attribute: **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/84v3qeyh/1/)**

```
class Tool {
 constructor (name, mainFunction) {
  this.name = name;
  this.mainFunction = mainFunction;
 }
 getName() {
   return this.name;
 }
 getMainFunction() {
   return this.mainFunction;
 }
}

var hammer = new Tool('hammer', 'bang on nails');
var saw = new Tool('saw', 'cuts heavy wood');
var toolbox = [hammer, saw];

for (let i in toolbox) {
  $('.wrapper').append('<div data-message="'+toolbox[i].getMainFunction()+'" class=\"'+toolbox[i].getName()+'  button\">'+toolbox[i].getName()+'</div>');
}

  $('.wrapper').on('click', '.button', function() {
    alert($(this).data('message'));
   });
```